# How can I change the default location of sidebar content folders to folders in partition shared by win7 & ubuntu

Tags: directory, default, location

I have a partition named Storage which is used by both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 where I have my music, videos, pictures and downloads.  I'd like to have the sidebar icons with these same names (eg. `Music`, `Pictures`, etc.) on Ubuntu link to the folders in Storage with the same name rather than `Home/Music` etc.
The problem is that I am super new to Ubuntu, I've been researching and i think it has to do with editing `~/.config/user-dir.dirs` but i have no idea how to navigate to this location, much less how to edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way for you could be this:

1. When you're in your **home folder** where you see "**Documents**", "**Music**", "**Pictures**" and "**Video**" in **Nautilus**, **press F3** which will switch to **dual-pane mode**.
2. Go to the **other pane** and click on the "**Storage**" partition to open it and make sure you have the **same folder names** there.
3. Now go back to the first pane (your **home folder**) and first check if these folders are **empty**. If they're not, **move** contents (select, press down Shift key, drag and drop) to the respective folders in the opposite pane (**Storage**). And now delete these empty folders (safer: **move to trash**).
4. Now go back to the second pane (**Storage**), select these folders, press down Ctrl+Shift, and then drag and drop to the first pane (your home folder) to create shortcuts (symbolic links) there.

That's it.
But you might also prefer to make your shared partition **Storage** mounted every time you login. Otherwise these links will look broken until you click and mount it. To do this you need to enter this partition in a system file called **fstab** like this:

1. Enter this command in Terminal (entering your login password when asked): `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
2. In this file add a line similar to the one below (assuming your partiton is in **ntfs** format, merely entering your partition uuid number instead of the example) at the end of the list:

   `UUID=5D07479B6A5F6512    /media/Storage    ntfs-3g    defaults,nls=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137      0    0`

You can get your partition uuid with this terminal command: `**ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid**`
Or you can start **GParted**, select the partition and then "**Information**" from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Another - More GUI - Way is using the **Ubuntu Tweak** tool to specify custom locations for those user folders.
To install, you need to enter the following commands (typing your **login password** when asked) in **Terminal**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Then start **Ubuntu Tweak**, go to **Admins** and then **User Folder**.
There you can select each user folder, click **Change** button at the bottom, and select the folder you want.

After this you might also prefer mounting the **Storage** partition each time you login by modifying the system file **fstab** as described in my first answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!...just got to try this today and worked perfect....tyvm

Comment: You're welcome... Would you like to mark one as the answer to your question then? Because many people don't do this, increasing  number of unanswered questions do not reflect the reality...